# How do I capture unicode character with swift regex

Tags: regex, swift, xcode, unicode

I have a String in Swift which looks as follows in the debugger of Xcode

> Random Text:  \u{e2}specificText:

When I print the text in the console of Xcode it looks like

> Random Text: ‎ specificText:

If I paste the text in question in some editor it looks like a bold dot.

Which regular expression do I have to use to just capture `\u{e2}` in the above text?
Which unicode character is that?

I am using the following String extension to get the captured groups:

```
extension String {
  func capturedGroups(forRegex regex: String) -> [String]? {
    guard let expression = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex) else { return nil }
    let matches = expression.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location:0, length: (self as NSString).count))
    guard let match = matches.first else { return nil }
    let lastRangeIndex = match.numberOfRanges - 1
    guard lastRangeIndex >= 1 else { return nil }
    var results = [String]()
    for i in 1...lastRangeIndex {
        let capturedGroupIndex = match.range(at: i)
        let matchedString = (self as NSString).substring(with: capturedGroupIndex)
        results.append(matchedString)
    }
    return results
  }
}
```

I have tried the following but it did not work

```
snippet.capturedGroups(forRegex: "(\\u00e2)")
```

Comment: Perhaps, it is [`â`](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%C3%A2).

Comment: This `\u{e2}` or this `\xe2` are good regex for that character. And, technically it's not a Unicode character since it's codepoint is less than 0x100 h.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I do not think so because when I print it it is invisble

Comment: @sin I tried this `snippet.capturedGroups(forRegex: "(\\u\\{e2\\})")` but it did not work

Comment: Why would you use regex for matching a specific literal string?

Comment: @CAustin I have to match some other part of the string which is unknown but follows a pattern. I omitted that part because it seemed irrelevant for this question.

Comment: If stringed, the variants are `"\\u{e2}"` or `"\\xe2"` or `"\\u00e2"` or `"\\x{e2}"` try them all. There are some octal forms too if need be.

Comment: @sin just tried all variants and none of them succeeded

Comment: Try the decomposition one. Reference: `â` LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX (U+00E2) with decomposition of LATIN SMALL LETTER A (U+0061) COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT (U+0302)

Comment: @sin sorry, I do not understand what you mean by that

Comment: See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e2/index.htm. Just make regex out of the decomposition (use all the  variants) Example: `\x{61}\x{302}` , etc... Many editors just show the rendered character as U+00E2 single character when it's possibly 2. Use a good hex editor to inspect the file's text.

Comment: @sin I do not think it is `â` because the character is invisible

Comment: This â should be two characters as opposed to this â which is one character. Copy them, individually into a text editor and check it's length. You may also use a regex with just the characters. Btw, decomposition is the _Unicode_ way of doing things.

Comment: @sin decomposition did not work either although I could find an `a` in the string because there is one in the beginning `snippet.capturedGroups(forRegex: "(\\u0061)")`. but this `line.capturedGroups(forRegex: "(\\u0061\\u0302)")` yields no results

Comment: @sin found the solution to the problem. was more related to Xcode. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged the strings containing `\u{e2}` with Xcode with the following code:

```
snippet.characters.forEach { character in
    print(character)
}
```

After setting a breakpoint at the `print` line I found out that although the Xcode debugger shows the following Unicode characters as `\u{e2}` when looking at the string the characters which I was actually confronted with were

> https://unicode-table.com/en/200E/
>
> https://unicode-table.com/en/202A/
>
> https://unicode-table.com/en/202C/

I could capture the unicode characters with the following code with my extension outlined in the question above:

```
snippet.capturedGroups(forRegex: "([\\u200E]{1})")
snippet.capturedGroups(forRegex: "([\\u202A]{1})")
snippet.capturedGroups(forRegex: "([\\u202C]{1})")
```